# Update Instagram user's access token programmatically

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Is there any way to programmatically update user's access_token, or request for new using using old? The problem is 5000 requests limit it's not enough for me, because my tool monitors media's like changes of each user and of all his media.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to get a new access_token is through the authorisation flow, which without the cookie for the users log on will require their username and password again.

Being able to refresh the access token programmatically would completely negate the point of api limits.